# Completing the next column series

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is not completely updated it is partially updated.
Ex - N8436001/002 and I want this to complete N8436001, N8436002. I am sharing a sample dataset and the expected dataset. Any help will be appreciated.

```
X <- c('N8436001','ACBRG001','ACFCU001','NE157001','FA300001','ADBDY001','AHLRZ001','AEADR001','ALGM2001','AMYH0001','AIMUT001','AJQ6F00C','A5NXR200')
Y <- c('002','4','003','003','2','3','002','002','ALHM6001','AMYH0003','2','00U','A5NXZ280')
Z <- c('NA','NA','012','NA','3','4','NA','003','3','4','NA','00V','289')  
P <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','4','AKGVD005','NA','NA','4','5','NA','NA','NA')
K <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','AKGVD007','NA','NA','NA','6','NA','NA','NA')

SamData <- data.frame(X,Y,Z,P,K)
```

Actual data
[image: ActualData]

Expected Output
[image: Expected Otput]

Comment: Your `NA` are quoted.  It should be without quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `substr` on the 'X' column and `paste` with the 'Y' column based on the number of characters in 'Y'

```
SamData[SamData == 'NA'] <- NA
SamData$X <- with(SamData,  paste0(substr(X, 1, nchar(X)- nchar(Y)), Y))
```

---

To do this for the whole dataset, use `lapply`

```
SamData[-1] <- lapply(SamData[-1], function(y) {
      i1 <- !is.na(y)
      y[i1] <- paste0(substr(SamData$X[i1], 1, nchar(SamData$X[i1]) -
                nchar(y[i1])), y[i1])
       y
     }
  )
```

If the columns are `factor` column, convert to `character`

```
SamData[-1] <- lapply(SamData[-1], function(y) {    
           i1 <- !is.na(y)
           y <- as.character(y)
        y[i1] <- paste0(substr(as.character(SamData$X[i1]), 1,
                nchar(as.character(SamData$X[i1])) -
                nchar(y[i1])), y[i1])
       y
     }
  )
```

-output

```
SamData
#          X        Y        Z        P        K
#1  N8436001 N8436002     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#2  ACBRG001 ACBRG004     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#3  ACFCU001 ACFCU003 ACFCU012     <NA>     <NA>
#4  NE157001 NE157003     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#5  FA300001 FA300002 FA300003 FA300004     <NA>
#6  ADBDY001 ADBDY003 ADBDY004 AKGVD005 AKGVD007
#7  AHLRZ001 AHLRZ002     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#8  AEADR001 AEADR002 AEADR003     <NA>     <NA>
#9  ALGM2001 ALHM6001 ALGM2003 ALGM2004     <NA>
#10 AMYH0001 AMYH0003 AMYH0004 AMYH0005 AMYH0006
#11 AIMUT001 AIMUT002     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#12 AJQ6F00C AJQ6F00U AJQ6F00V     <NA>     <NA>
#13 A5NXR200 A5NXZ280 A5NXR289     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Hi @akrun may i know did you convert the it to character to get the final output. I am not get the same as you are getting using the above, If I ran directly I am getting this error Error in nchar(SamData$X[i1]) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector. If I convert it usis as.character. I am getting the output as "c(12c(4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4)" "c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3)"    
. Please help

Comment: @JK1185 I am using `R 4.0.2` and in it by default the `data.frame` uses `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  If you have an older version, it would be a factor column (?).  You can do `as.character` inside the `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the `tidyverse` (and quoted `NA`s):

```r
library(dplyr)

X <- c('N8436001','ACBRG001','ACFCU001','NE157001','FA300001','ADBDY001','AHLRZ001','AEADR001','ALGM2001','AMYH0001','AIMUT001','AJQ6F00C','A5NXR200')
Y <- c('002','4','003','003','2','3','002','002','ALHM6001','AMYH0003','2','00U','A5NXZ280')
Z <- c('NA','NA','012','NA','3','4','NA','003','3','4','NA','00V','289')  
P <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','4','AKGVD005','NA','NA','4','5','NA','NA','NA')
K <- c('NA','NA','NA','NA','NA','AKGVD007','NA','NA','NA','6','NA','NA','NA')

SamData <- data.frame(X,Y,Z,P,K)

SamData <- SamData %>% 
  mutate(across(-X, ~if_else(.x == "NA",
                               "NA",
                               paste0(substr(X, 1, nchar(X) - nchar(.x)),
                                      .x))))
SamData
#>           X        Y        Z        P        K
#> 1  N8436001 N8436002       NA       NA       NA
#> 2  ACBRG001 ACBRG004       NA       NA       NA
#> 3  ACFCU001 ACFCU003 ACFCU012       NA       NA
#> 4  NE157001 NE157003       NA       NA       NA
#> 5  FA300001 FA300002 FA300003 FA300004       NA
#> 6  ADBDY001 ADBDY003 ADBDY004 AKGVD005 AKGVD007
#> 7  AHLRZ001 AHLRZ002       NA       NA       NA
#> 8  AEADR001 AEADR002 AEADR003       NA       NA
#> 9  ALGM2001 ALHM6001 ALGM2003 ALGM2004       NA
#> 10 AMYH0001 AMYH0003 AMYH0004 AMYH0005 AMYH0006
#> 11 AIMUT001 AIMUT002       NA       NA       NA
#> 12 AJQ6F00C AJQ6F00U AJQ6F00V       NA       NA
#> 13 A5NXR200 A5NXZ280 A5NXR289       NA       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi, @starja I tried your approach but am getting the same as the input. May I know if you did any processing in between.

Comment: I also use `R 4.0.2`, so maybe try `SamData <- data.frame(X, Y, Z, P, K, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`